# Python - Acquiring variables with vbscript

Tags: python, vbscript

I'm working on a python code that calls a VB script aiming to perform some calculations. These calculations MUST be performed in the VB script and there is no way to migrate them to the Python one.

I send the variables in the VB script like this:

```
WScript.Echo("TEST")
```

And try to acquire them in the Python code as:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cscript.exe', VB_path, nLM, nSD, nSO, nTWS, nROH, 
                      nMOH1, nMOH2, nRad1, nRad3, nLstk, nT_Shaft_EN, S_path, 
                      S_file, S_version, nkE_ref, nTC_ref, nNImax, nCost_PM, 
                      nCost_Steel, nCost_Wire, '//nologo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
out
```

The result I get for "out" is the following:

```
b'Test\r\n'
```

My question is: how I can send several outputs with the plain variable ? Also, as a bonus question, is there any obvious way to send an array in this kind of way from vb to the python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since text (through a stdout stream) is your method of communication, the obvious way to send multiple values (a data structure) is to serialize it in a well-known format that both communication partners can agree on.

A common way to do this would be JSON, but JSON is comparatively hard to generate with vanilla VBScript. Other obvious candidates would be CSV, or XML, or INI, but ultimately: any format you can dream up.

The advantage of choosing well-known formats is that somebody else will already have written a parser for them. Formats you come up with require that you write the parser yourself.

Let's assume that the INI format is capable of representing your data:

```
[section]
key_a = value_a
key_b = value_b
```

This kind of output is easy to generate in VBScript, and Python has [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to read it.

So we could write a couple of helpers in VBScript:

```
Sub OutputSection(name)
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "[" & name & "]")
End Sub

Sub OutputVariable(name, value)
    Dim i
    If IsArray(value) Then
        If UBound(value) = -1 Then
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(name & ". = ")    ' to signify empty array
        Else
            For i = 0 To UBound(value) - 1
                OutputVariable(name & "." & i, value(i))
            Next
        End If
    Else
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(name & " = " & value)
    End IF
End Sub
```

Calling these in your script would generated neatly organized output

```
[main]
key = value

[some_array]
array.0 = value0
array.1 = value1
array.2 = value2
```

In Python you could add a post-processing step that turns the individual array items into lists.

Or, you use `Join()` in VBScript for arrays, which would make both the `Sub OutputVariable()` and the parsing on the Python end simpler, but you run the risk of mangling your data if the list delimiter can occur in an array value. It's a trade-off.